# PostBackUrl with query string is taking me to original root URL always

Tags: asp.net, query-string, postbackurl

I am new to web development. I have a simple question

I have the following server side code

> linkButton.PostBackUrl =
>   "PageRedirect.aspx?Link=" + values[1];

When I click on the link, it takes me to the root website passing values[1] to it

http://localhost:3783/MyWebsite/www.facebook.com

which actually doesn't exist

note that PageRedirect.aspx exists directly under the original root as well as the page from which the code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Does changing it to this work?

```
linkButton.PostBackUrl = "~/PageRedirect.aspx?Link=" + values[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that all values[1] (the link) should start with http:// otherwise it will not recognize it